# Which Tool To Use? Automate field update from old opp to a new created opp record

Tags: nonprofit-starter-pack

I am working with a nonprofit. We have memberships that are renewed every year or so. Below scenario is on opportunity records that belong to the same contact record.

Scenario: Every time membership is purchased - the system creates new opportunities. In some cases, members are renewing their membership before the end date of existing membership(opportunity). For that reason, I need to set a field value ending membership date of old opportunity to a new one when new opp is created. So that I can set the formula below to update field.

If correct info was on the same record this formula would work on flow.

```
IF( TODAY() < {!vOppRecord_Ass.npe01__Membership_End_Date__c}, ADDMONTHS({!vOppRecord_Ass.npe01__Membership_End_Date__c},12), ADDMONTHS(TODAY(),12))
```

My challenge is, getting a value from an old opportunity end date to end date of the new one. What tool I can use in such a case?

Appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option besides Apex code, if you're going about it by building automation, is a Flow launched by Process Builder. That Flow would need to look up existing Opportunities related to the same Account which are in the appropriate status, determine the furthest-out end date, and then populate that value in the new record.

It's possible you don't need to do that, however. You can create native Roll-Up Summary Fields that aggregate from the Opportunity to the Account, and you can roll up the `MAX()` value of some date field. If the criteria for identifying current membership opportunities are simple enough to be permitted in a Roll-Up Summary Field's criteria, you could just build a rollup on the Account to capture the latest end date and populate it onto new Opportunities with Process Builder. Alternately, [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) can facilitate more complex rollups.

That doesn't take into account NPSP's Soft Credit mechanisms, however, which may significantly complicate the picture to the extent that Flow or Apex is required.

One possibly solution that does handle Soft Credits is the NPSP's native [Customizable Rollups](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Create-Customizable-Rollup) facility. Again, if you're able to get your latest membership date rolled up to the relevant Opportunity parent (Account or Primary Contact), your work dramatically simplifies to a Process rather than a Flow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer above. I ended up getting it done through process builder + flow.  I am currently in the process of learning the NPSP pack. Appreciate your time and effort!